# Setting up custom distributed cache manager with Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, shiro, distributed-caching

Can anyone outline, maybe with some brief examples or pseudo-code, how a custom distributed cache manager implementation would look using Apache Shiro for a web application with multiple servers. For example, if I wanted to use a remote SQL database for storing the session, authN and authZ data (it doesn't have to be an SQL database though, anything is fine so I can get an idea of how a custom implementation would look).

What's there in the Apache Shiro docs is good, but the caching docs are incomplete, and the info on distributed caching focuses on the necessary configuration in `shiro.ini` (unless I've missed some of the documentation).

Any links to good articles or blogs would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://github.com/zhangkaitao/shiro-example/blob/master/shiro-example-chapter10/src/main/java/com/github/zhangkaitao/shiro/chapter10/session/dao/MySessionDao.java

There's some info here from 2011: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Storing-sessins-in-an-RDBMS-instead-of-an-enterprise-cache-td5645213.html